# How to get content from WebView in jetpack compose

Tags: webview, android-jetpack-compose, contenteditable

I have editable webview. I'm using webview as rich text editor.
WebViewClient as AccompanistWebViewClient.

And on onPageFinished I have css injection to webview
`view?.evaluateJavascript(js, null)`

but how can I return content from webview?
I want retrieve webview content from my ViewModel class

```
val fullContentHtml =
        rememberWebViewStateWithHTMLData(data = "$contentEditableHtml$messageContentHtml</div>")
        WebView(
            modifier = Modifier
                //.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(horizontal = 8.dp),
            state = fullContentHtml,
            onCreated = { webView ->
                webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
            },
            client = remember { webViewClient },
            chromeClient =
            remember {
                chromeViewClient
            }
        )
```

Comment: Do you want to pass data from webview to android?

Comment: Yes, my webview is editable. And via ViewModel I want to retrieve data from webview

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to communicate to Android System using Webview In Jetpack Compose.

Here we have taken a sample HTML file and a simple JavaScript Function.

After that make an interface which will deal with JavaScript and act upon it.

**Sample HTML File with JavaScript**

```
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
           function init()
           {
              var testVal = 'Hello Android !!';
              AndroidFunction.showToast(testVal);
           }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="clear: both;height: 3px;"> </div>
<div>
    <p><h1>Jetpack Compose Webview Communication Example</h1></p>
    <input value="submit" type="button" name="submit"
           id="btnSubmit" onclick="javascript:return init();" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Make an interface to deal with JavaScript**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
import android.widget.Toast

class JavaScriptInterface {

    private val context : Context

    constructor(context : Context){
        this.context = context
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun showToast(str : String){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Message Received From Java Script $str", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
import android.webkit.WebView
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView

@Composable
fun WebViewCommunication(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        AndroidView(factory = { context ->
            WebView(context).apply {
                settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
                settings.useWideViewPort = true
                settings.setSupportZoom(true)

                addJavascriptInterface(JavaScriptInterface(context), "AndroidFunction")
                loadUrl("file:///android_asset/my.html")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Your js return value by pushing Botton. But if I need took text which user have written in webview?

Comment: I have contenteditable="true" in my JS, and I need somehow catch from modelview text which user have written in webview.

Comment: You need to playaround with this code to achieve desired output. for e.g you can use javascript method which automatically fires this logic.